# What does proto-idealistic philosophy mean?

Tags: kant

I am listening to a lecture on YT (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbvG4KffgSI skip to 2:41) and the lecturer mentioned "Immanuel Kant's proto-idealistic philosophy."

What does that mean?

Comment: Which lecture were you listening to? This would help provide context.

Comment: It's this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbvG4KffgSI (skip to 2:42)

Comment: Thank you.  I edited the question and added the link.  You may further edit this.

Comment: Prolegomena https://www.earlymoderntexts.com/assets/pdfs/kant1783.pdf

Comment: German Idealism https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_idealism

Comment: I take "Proto" to mean first (conservative) model. Kant took as little as possible "into subject" (idealizing move) but even so it was "revolutionary".  See Ch. 3 this article Copernican Revolution. IEP https://www.iep.utm.edu/kantmeta/

Comment: "Proto" typically refers to a germ/seed of something that develops later. In this case, from context, the author casts Kant's philosophy as the seed of German idealism ("*Kant is who made Hegel possible*"). It is a rather strange characterization since idealism far predates Hegel, and Kant developed his philosophy in direct opposition to a classical version of it (Leibniz's). One can equally say that Kant's "transcendental idealism" was proto-anti-realist, and German idealism emerged to "save" idealism after his rather damaging critique of the general idea.

Comment: OK, I need to read a shed loads of stuff now (Idealism, Kant's position, Hegel etc) I thought I could get a layman's answer but apparently not.

Comment: The most probable answer in layman terms that is not incorrect is given in the first two sentences of @Conifold's comment: Kant's philosophy was the seed of German Idealism (because it emphasised idealistic intakes to our cognition the British Empiricists (esp. Locke and Hume) ignored). Really, the term is also a bad choice, since the idealistic intake was deliberately held at check by Kant - by design. It is not in the usual sense a "not fully developed idealism" like in "proto-type", but a philosophy that was deliberately developed *beyond* the dichotomy of developed empirism and idealism.